# Select Sum from 1 table

Tags: sql, math, logic

Hello i want to sum values from 1 column but some values from this table i want to multiply with -1. For example i have this table:

[pictab1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT04u.png)

I want sum column B but where in column A is - i want to subtract those value from those with +
My idea is

```
select ((select sum(Column B) from T1 WHERE Column A='+')+                            
  (-1*(select sum(Column B)from T1 WHERE Column A='-') from T1
```

The result of this select is

```
45  
45  
45  
45
```

I want my select to show only one 45.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN A='-' THEN -B ELSE B END)
FROM Table
```